# Process faillure error 502.5 in prod only - .net core referencing .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I have an angular 2 application running on .net core referencing .net framework 4.6.1.

The applicaton works fine on my dev machine and on the preprod server.

But when I publish to the prod server I get this error when trying to access the application : HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

I'm not getting any logs in \logs\stdout, actually the logs folder doesn't even get created. I even tried to grant full control to Everyone on the application folder.

Event viewer is not helping

This is the most info that I found in a log file =>

Sig[8].Value=System.MissingMethodException

from :

> Version=1 EventType=CLR20r3 EventTime=131387567139231405 ReportType=2
>   Consent=1 ReportIdentifier=10cef250-343f-11e7-a6e0-0050569458bd
>   IntegratorReportIdentifier=10cef24f-343f-11e7-a6e0-0050569458bd
>   Response.type=4 Sig[0].Name=Problem Signature 01
>   Sig[0].Value=MyWebApp.exe Sig[1].Name=Problem Signature 02
>   Sig[1].Value=1.0.0.0 Sig[2].Name=Problem Signature 03
>   Sig[2].Value=5910e098 Sig[3].Name=Problem Signature 04
>   Sig[3].Value=System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource Sig[4].Name=Problem
>   Signature 05 Sig[4].Value=1.0.24212.1 Sig[5].Name=Problem Signature 06
>   Sig[5].Value=575cf9f2 Sig[6].Name=Problem Signature 07 Sig[6].Value=1c
>   Sig[7].Name=Problem Signature 08 Sig[7].Value=5 Sig[8].Name=Problem
>   Signature 09 Sig[8].Value=System.MissingMethodException
>   DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
>   DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID DynamicSig[2].Value=1033
>   DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1 DynamicSig[22].Value=4004
>   DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
>   DynamicSig[23].Value=40041fa9eec4919e82227ef8fa46ea38
>   DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3 DynamicSig[24].Value=54cd
>   DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
>   DynamicSig[25].Value=54cd4d251c94103b3771231ce68bff8d
>   UI[2]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\MyWebApp.exe UI[5]=Check online for a
>   solution (recommended) UI[6]=Check for a solution later (recommended)
>   UI[7]=Close UI[8]=MyWebApp.exe stopped working and was closed UI[9]=A
>   problem caused the application to stop working correctly. Windows will
>   notify you if a solution is available. UI[10]=&Close
>   LoadedModule[0]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\MyWebApp.exe
>   LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
>   LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
>   LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\SYSFER.DLL
>   LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
>   LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>   LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
>   LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
>   LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
>   LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
>   LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
>   LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
>   LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
>   LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
>   LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
>   LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
>   LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
>   LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
>   LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
>   LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR120_CLR0400.dll
>   LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\mscorlib\701f2b79b02a02beba70e50bb2edb212\mscorlib.ni.dll LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
>   LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
>   LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
>   LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
>   LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
>   LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
>   LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
>   LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
>   LoadedModule[29]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[30]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
>   LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll
>   LoadedModule[33]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll
>   LoadedModule[34]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables.dll
>   LoadedModule[35]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll
>   LoadedModule[36]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[37]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[38]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[39]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.dll
>   LoadedModule[40]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.dll
>   LoadedModule[41]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
>   LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
>   LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
>   LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
>   LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Globalization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Globalization.dll
>   LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Resources.ResourceManager\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
>   LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\43abfb4b83df5a0837f77bd240c39b53\System.Core.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[48]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.dll
>   LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\edc284c2fc5f774b65992c5e0b6a1899\System.ni.dll
>   LoadedModule[51]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
>   LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ComponentModel.dll
>   LoadedModule[53]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll
>   LoadedModule[54]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[55]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.dll
>   LoadedModule[56]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
>   LoadedModule[57]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
>   LoadedModule[58]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll
>   LoadedModule[59]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
>   LoadedModule[60]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll
>   LoadedModule[61]=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
>   LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll
>   LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Tracing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
>   LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
>   LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
>   FriendlyEventName=Stopped working ConsentKey=CLR20r3
>   AppName=MyWebApp.exe AppPath=D:\wwwroot_prod\MyWebApp2\MyWebApp.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,

I tought the problem was with .net core, but the prod server did not have the .net framework 4.6.1 installed

I installed 4.6.2 and now it works